# Слишком медленно выполняется MySQL запрос

Tags: mysql

Слишком долго выполняется запрос MySQL:

```
    SELECT winlogs.image, winlogs.winitem, winlogs.grade, winlogs.caseid, winlogs.status, winlogs.price, winlogs.id, lockeditems.tradeid, cases.image AS caseimg, cases.grade AS casegrade, items.preview
    FROM winlogs 
    LEFT JOIN lockeditems ON lockeditems.asset = winlogs.asset 
    LEFT JOIN cases ON winlogs.caseid = cases.caseid 
    LEFT JOIN b_items ON b_items.asset = winlogs.asset
    WHERE winlogs.userid = '616632589'
    ORDER BY winlogs.time DESC LIMIT 1, 25;
```

В таблицах:
winlogs: 5500 строк 10 столбцов, есть текст
lockeditems: 2 строки 7 стобцов
cases: 50 строк 15 столбцов
b_items: 1000 строк 12 столбцов, есть текст
userid = # пользователя.

Изначально запрос работал быстро, когда у пользователя в winlogs было всего например 100-150 строчек.
Сейчас у данного юзера 616632589 около 1300 строчек побед (в таблице winlogs), поэтому и сам запрос срабатывает 3 секунды (замерял через show profiles), когда его профиль открываешь, жуткие тормоза. Не говорю уж о том, что будет, когда у пользователя будет 10000+ побед..

Что можно придумать, чтобы ускорить выполнение запроса? Таблицы трогать/совместить не получится.

Comment: Выполните, пожалуйста эту же команду вместе с командой `EXPLAIN` (`EXPLAIN SELECT...`) и добавьте результат, возможно, так ситуация станет более ясной.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить индекс на поле `winlogs.userid`. Также можно добавить индексы по всем столбцам, используемым во фразах `ON`.

Для более детальной оптимизации можно порекомендовать почитать книгу "MySQL. Оптимизация производительности" (в особенности 4ую главу - "Оптимизация запросов").

Comment: У автора вопроса настолько смешные объемы таблиц (ну, если только в числе 5500 не потерялось несколько нулей), что становится сомнительно, что проблема в отсутствии индексов. Хотя, конечно, индексы - это первое, что приходит в голову.

Comment: @Yaant, да, согласна. Для того, чтобы можно было сказать что-то более точно, можно попробовать посмотреть на результаты этого же запроса с `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать.

Comment: @Ksenia выполнил с explain : http://clip2net.com/clip/m0/96d28-clip-13kb.png?nocache=1 , все плохо?)

Comment: @Ksenia в конечном итоге вышло что-то такое: http://clip2net.com/clip/m0/72600-clip-14kb.png?nocache=1 , в итоге время выполнения уже не 3+ секунды а ~0.007 сек (проставил 3 индекса).

Comment: @Yaant 5 тысяч строк уже не очень смешно без индексов, это постоянный обход диска/ssd,  может быть незаметно при малом количестве запросов, но при частых одновременных запросах - будет тормозить.

Comment: @strangeqargo При частых запросах такая таблица скорее всего будет вся висеть в кэше, и обращений к диску не будет вовсе. :)

Comment: @Yaant это если включен кэш, и в любом случае, без индексов, даже при чтении из памяти, при большом количестве запросов - будет медленней, а если в таблицы еще и запись ведется (например, таблица маленькая, но новые записи не добавляются, но апдейтятся часто) - еще как будут обращения к диску. Индексы не от балды придумали

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте составной индекс winlogs.userid, winlogs.time , поскольку userid в where, а time в order. В итоге просматриваются все записи